# Trying to write a function to return a data frame in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I tried writing a function to return a data frame and when I try to run 
cc <- complete("specdata", c(6, 10, 20, 34, 100, 200, 310))
I get an error message of "Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection"
Please help (see code below). Thank you

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

  y <- vector()

  for(i in 1:length(id)){

    x <- id
    y <- c(y, sum(complete.cases(
      read.csv(as.character(paste0("specdata","/","f",id[i],".csv"))))))
  }
  df <- data.frame(x, y)

  colnames(df) <- c("id","ret")

  return(df)
}
```

Comment: the error stems from R not finding a csv file with that name in the work directory, but I can spot a couple of potential issues: 1 are you sure you don't want `x  <- id[i]` instead of  `x <- id ` ? 2 why do you have an escape character in the middle of the name of your file ?

Comment: "Cannot open the connection" makes it sound like you are trying to read a file that isn't there. Rather than construct file names with `paste`, maybe use `list.files` to pull the file names from the folder? Something like `files = list.files(pattern = "f[0-9]+.csv", path = "specdata")`, maybe with `full.names = T`

Comment: @Mouad_S I think that's part of a relative path. So like this: `"specdata/f10.csv"`. Also, nowhere in your function uses `directory`, you should replace `"specdata"` in `paste0` with `directory` so the function returns what you want when you use another directory.

Comment: Also, though not wrong it's unnecessary to do `as.character(paste0(...))`. `paste0` returns a character vector.